# $\mathbb{S}[q^{-1}]$  is Moore spectrum $M(\mathbb{Z}[q^{-1}],0)$?

Tags: homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy-theory

Let $S[q^{-1}]$ denote the homotopy colimit of the sequence $S\overset{q}\to S\overset{q}\to\cdots$ where $S$ denotes the sphere spectrum. Is it then the case that $S[q^{-1}]$ is the Moore spectrum of $\mathbb{Z}[q^{-1}]$?  This seems intuitively obvious, and I imagine I'd like to make the argument: $$[S,H\mathbb{Z}\wedge S[q^{-1}]]\cong[S,H(\mathbb{Z}[q^{-1}])]\cong \mathbb{Z}[q^{-1}], $$ but I'm not sure how to get the first isomorphism. I believe to some this may be a standard fact or trivially true (unless of course it's false) but I'm interested in how to rigorously prove such a thing, i.e. what is the interaction between the functor $H:Rng\to Spectra$ with various algebraic operations?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jon, shouldn't $S[q^{-1}]$ be the homotopy LIMIT instead of colimit if you want to invert $q$?

Comment: Oh, even I should be able to answer this by now...

Comment: It is colimit woops!

Comment: @EldenElmanto you mean colimit?

Comment: lol yeah - I am crazy